# Trouble if a directory exists

Tags: bash, shell-script, bioinformatics

I've got the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line
do
echo "line" $line
if [[ -d ../Results/${line}_Forward && -d ../Results/${line}_Reverse ]]
then

        cd ../Results/COMBI
        mkdir ./${line}_COMBI
        cd ..
        for (( win = 2; win < 20; win += 2 )); do
        printf 'The value of win is %d, now entereing inner loop\n' "$win"

        for (( per = 50; per < 100; per += 2 )); do
            printf 'Value of per is %d\n' "$per"
            merger -asequence ./${line}_Forward/${line}_Forward_Trimmed_w${win}_p${per}.fa -bsequence ./${line}_Reverse/REV_COMP/${line}_Reverse_Trimmed_w${win}_p${per}_RevComp.fa -outseq ./COMBI/${line}_COMBI/${line}_w${win}_p${per}_COMBI.fa
        done
        done
else
    echo $line "Forward or Reverse directory does not exist"
fi
done < ./Data_ORD.txt
```

When i run the script any dictory contained in the if statment exits but they actually do. And i get this kind of output for each line in Data_ORD.txt:

```
line  ORD0926
 Forward or Reverse directory does not exist
```

in the last `echo` $line variable is not printed. I guess something is wrong with this variable but or with the if statement.

Any idea's why $line is not printed in the last echo and directories are not recognized by the if statement?

**.fa: fasta formats which are plain text formats containing DNA sequences.
**merger command: contained in the EMBOSS package "The European Molecular Biology Open Software Suite"

Comment: Do `cat -A` on your input file, see if it ends with a newline ( so look for `$` in the last line ). If it doesn't, it can explain why last `echo` doesn't print out `$line`.  I can't see what potential issue with `if` statement could be. Are you checking whether both directories exist or do you need to have just one exit ?

Comment: Im checking whether if both directories exist. I created a new variable after then which cuts codes contained in the data file: wth=`echo ${line} |  cut -c 1-7` and it solved the problem!  what is used cat -A for?

Comment: `cat -A` shows the non-visible characters, for example newlines.  Do `printf "one\ntwo" | cat -A` and you'll see what i mean

Comment: (@Serg) `cat -A` on GNU, or `cat -v` anywhere, also shows if the lines are terminated by Windows-style CRLF instead of LF; that would explain both the `-d` tests failing _and_ the 'missing' (actually overwritten) value in the error message for each line.

Comment: Neuls: FYI in bash (and _some_ other shells) you can just do `${line:0:7}` Or you can remove the _last_ char _if_ it's CR with `${line%$'\r'}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im checking whether if both directories exist. I created a new variable after then which cuts codes contained in the data file: wth=echo ${line} | cut -c 1-7

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line
do
echo "line" $line
wth=`echo ${line} |  cut -c 1-7`
echo "wth" ${wth}
if [[ -d ../Results/${wth}_Forward && -d ../Results/${wth}_Reverse ]]
then

        cd ../Results/COMBI
        mkdir ./${wth}_COMBI
        cd ..
        for (( win = 2; win < 20; win += 2 )); do
        printf 'The value of win is %d, now entereing inner loop\n' "$win"

        for (( per = 50; per < 100; per += 2 )); do
            printf 'Value of per is %d\n' "$per"
            merger -asequence ./${wth}_Forward/${wth}_Forward_Trimmed_w${win}_p${per}.fa -bsequence ./${wth}_Reverse/REV_COMP/${wth}_Reverse_w${win}_p${per}_RevComp.fa -outfile none -outseq ./COMBI/${wth}_COMBI/${wth}_w${win}_p${per}_COMBI.fa
        done
        done
else
    echo ${wth} "Forward or Reverse directory does not exist"
fi
done < ./Data_ORD.txt
```

Now the script works. It seems calling directly $line as a variable isn't a good idea since there can be some unseen spaces.

Comment: There are various things wrong with this script (first of all, you're not quoting your variables which is why spaces will break it) but it's hard to help since you haven't explained what you're actually trying to do and it is not easy to guess what your directory structure is. Also, it looks like you're aligning forward and reverse strands. What's the point in doing that?

Comment: do you mean quoting a variable like "${line}"? Is it a good idea to do it always? well i got the trouble when checking if the directories existed, they did but the if statement wast recognizing it. I somehow found out that it was due to $line var so i corrected it with cutting it into a new variable (wth).
I'm aligning forward and reverse complementary DNA strands in order to get a better quality merged strand

Comment: Yes, like `"${line}"` or just `"$line". I'm sure we could help more if you gave a more comprehensive example. As for the alignment, I've never used `merger` and just glanced at the manual where it mentioned it does a Needlman-Wunsch alignment, but missed that it's designed for overlapping sequences. I get it now.